# Create Hive table from multiple Excel files

Tags: excel, hive, format

What is the best way to load Excel files to a Hive table?
Is there a command to change them to tab delimited format?

Comment: I have more than few hundred files so was wondering if I can run a command to do this in one go?

Comment: So Basically I have a folder with 100 excel files and need to write them to a table in hive.

Comment: Hive doesn't natively read Excel files so you might find it easiest to write a script in Excel which loops through all your files and exports them as CSV, which Hive can read much more easily.

Answer (score 1):

You could look at something with tika parsing, or apache pos parsing for xls spreadsheets.

https://poi.apache.org/
https://tika.apache.org/

You'll need a java-ish language to use this stuff, so consider groovy, jython, clojure, scala, or if you know it java.

I'm doing something similar with a bunch of xlsx files already in hdfs, with this sort of pre-processing before the output ends up in hive.    Hopefully your xlsx sheets are somewhat straight forward and just resemble 2d datasets.  (embedded pivot tables, charts, etc. don't come across into hive with any context.)

Good luck, it's not pretty... xls is tuff to work with because it's just so flexible.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the newest version of the HadoopOffice library which has a HiveSerde for Excel files https://github.com/ZuInnoTe/hadoopoffice/wiki